# How to use NSPredicate to filter based on child elements?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm using Core Data; let's say that I have a many-to-one relationship between employees and departments, and employees are stored in an `NSSet` in each department. I want to find all the departments that only have one employee. How do I do this with Core Data?

I tried the below code and I get an exception saying that MYEmployee doesn't respond to `allObjects`.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.employees.allObjects.count == 1"];
singleEmployeeDepartments = [[myModelController allDepartments] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Comment: My code block above is all one line. When I try to start the next line with singleEmployeeDepartments it breaks the code Markdown. What gives?

Comment: The backticks are only for inline code formatting. For multi-line code blocks, indent each line 4 spaces. You can also select the text and hit the {} above the editing field or Control-K.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you're not using Core Data efficiently here, because you are always fetching all departments from the data store and then filtering the resulting array in memory. You can query the managed object context directly for matching departments, instead of fetching all departments, which can reduce memory consumption and might also be faster if you have a lot of departments.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = ...;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Department" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employees.@count == 1"]];
NSArray *singleEmployeeDepartments = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
```

The other key part is to use the `@count` operator in the predicate string to query departments that have a specific number of employees.

Comment: thank you, it worked, and thank you for the efficiency tip. I already need to query for the whole array for a different purpose though. Also I thought that NSSet didn't respond to count but I guess since it is in NSPredicate and is an aggregate function it works?

Comment: A quick question: where @count is documented? It is used here indirectly https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB